# Masonry Called Correctly But Doesn't Align Grid

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I am attempting to install the masonry.js library into my website.
But no matter what I add/remove, Masonry just doesn't appear to align anything on the webpage.

This is my code:

```
<script>
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  // options...
});
// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry('layout');
});
</script>
```

And my HTML/PHP

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="grid">
        <div id="row" >
                <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?> 
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="grid-item"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/page.php?page=<?php echo $page['slug']; ?>"><img alt="Article Image" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?><?php echo $page['image']; ?>"></div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any assistance at all would be greatly appreciated, I've gone through several articles about installing Masonry with Bootstrap, but no matter what I attempt, it still refuses to align
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDwPy.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Modified

```
<div class="grid">
```

To

```
<div class="grid js-masonry">
```

Which has now done the trick. :)